# Prove difference of simple functions is a simple function.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove difference of simple functions is a simple function.

**My attempt:**

Let $(X,\mathbb{A})$ a measure space, $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i1_{A_i}$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nd_j1_{B_j}$

We know:

$$f(x)-g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i1_{A_i}-\sum_{j=1}^nd_j1_{B_j}=\sum_{i,j=1}^nc_i1_{A_i}-d_j1_{B_j}$$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: A simple function is constant on a finite number of segments. What are these segments for $f-g$? The way I think of it, it suffices to show it for addition (since $f-g = f + (-g)$ and $(-g)$ is simple). Then I think of stacking two simple functions on top of each other - where is the new function constant?

Comment: @Bvss12, if you're struggling for intuition, consider "disjointifying" the sets $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_j\}$ into $C_{ij} = A_i \cap B_j$. How many $C_{ij}$ are there?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to see it:

A function is simple **iff** it is measurable and has finite range.

Let $\square$ be $+,-$,or $\cdot$, then
if $s_1,s_2$ are simple, then $s_1 \square s_2$ has finite range and is measurable and
so it simple.